# How to create a loop based on click of RadioButton in Python

Tags: python, user-interface, for-loop

I have written the following code to present certain select options based on the click of the user. So if the user clicks the first RadioButton (value 1) only one option will appear, if they click the second RadioButton (value 2) two will appear etc... This will go until the value 10 (where they will have 10 options).

```
class MedTimes:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.fr = LabelFrame(master, text = "Time to take Medication")
        self.fr.grid(row = 6, column = 0, columnspan = 4, padx=8,pady=8, sticky='we')

        Label(self.fr, text = "How many times a day do you need to take your medication?").grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = 'e', columnspan = 3)

        self.y = IntVar ()
        self.y.set(1)

        Radiobutton(self.fr,text = "Once",  fg = "dark green", variable = self.y, value = 1, padx = 20, command = self.timings).grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = 'w')
        Radiobutton(self.fr,text = "Twice", fg = "dark green", variable = self.y, value = 2, padx = 20, command = self.timings).grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = 'w')
        Radiobutton(self.fr,text = "Three times", fg = "dark green", variable = self.y, value = 3, padx = 20, command = self.timings).grid(row = 3, column = 1, sticky = 'w')
        Radiobutton(self.fr,text = "Four times", fg = "dark green", variable = self.y, value = 4, padx = 20, command = self.timings).grid(row = 4, column = 1, sticky = 'w')
        Radiobutton(self.fr,text = "Five times", fg = "dark green", variable = self.y, value = 5, padx = 20, command = self.timings).grid(row = 5, column = 1, sticky = 'w')
        Radiobutton(self.fr,text = "Six times", fg = "dark green", variable = self.y, value = 6, padx = 20, command = self.timings).grid(row = 1, column = 2, sticky = 'w') 
        Radiobutton(self.fr,text = "Seven times", fg = "dark green", variable = self.y, value = 7, padx = 20, command = self.timings).grid(row = 2, column = 2, sticky = 'w')   
        Radiobutton(self.fr,text = "Eight times", fg = "dark green", variable = self.y, value = 8, padx = 20, command = self.timings).grid(row = 3, column = 2, sticky = 'w')
        Radiobutton(self.fr,text = "Nine times", fg = "dark green", variable = self.y, value = 9, padx =20, command = self.timings).grid(row = 4, column = 2, sticky = 'w') 
        Radiobutton(self.fr,text = "Ten times", fg = "dark green", variable = self.y, value = 10, padx =20, command = self.timings ).grid(row = 5, column = 2, sticky = 'w')

    def timings(self):
        currentValue = self.y.get()
        #creating an array to hold the values oh hour and then minute (at a 5 min interval
        timelistHour = ["00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23"]
        timelistMinute = ["00", "05", "10", "15", "20", "25", "30", "35", "40", "45", "50", "55"]
        if currentValue == 1:
            timeHourOne = StringVar()
            timeHourOne.set(timelistHour[0])
            timeMinOne = StringVar()
            timeMinOne.set(timelistMinute[0])
            Label(self.fr, text = "Hour/Min :").grid(row = 6, column = 1, sticky = 'w')
            OptionMenu(self.fr, timeHourOne, *timelistHour).grid(row = 6, column = 1, sticky = 'e')
            Label(self.fr, text = "Minute :").grid(row = 6, column = 2, sticky = 'w')
            OptionMenu(self.fr, timeMinOne, *timelistMinute).grid(row = 6, column = 2, sticky = 'w')                
        elif currentValue == 2:
            timeHourTwo = StringVar()
            timeHourTwo.set(timelistHour[0])
            timeMinTwo = StringVar()
            timeMinTwo.set(timelistMinute[0])
            Label(self.fr, text = "Hour :").grid(row = 6, column = 0, sticky = 'e')
            OptionMenu(self.fr, timeHourTwo, *timelistHour).grid(row = 6, column = 1, sticky = 'w')
            Label(self.fr, text = "Minute :").grid(row = 6, column = 1, sticky = 'e')
            OptionMenu(self.fr, timeMinTwo, *timelistMinute).grid(row = 6, column = 2, sticky = 'w')
            Label(self.fr, text = "Hour :").grid(row = 7, column = 0, sticky = 'e')
            OptionMenu(self.fr, timeHourTwo, *timelistHour).grid(row = 7, column = 1, sticky = 'w')
            Label(self.fr, text = "Minute :").grid(row = 7, column = 1, sticky = 'e')
            OptionMenu(self.fr, timeMinTwo, *timelistMinute).grid(row = 7, column = 2, sticky = 'w')
        elif currentValue == 3:
            timeHourThree = StringVar()
            timeHourThree.set(timelistHour[0])
            timeMinThree = StringVar()
            timeMinThree.set(timelistMinute[0])
            Label(self.fr, text = "Hour :").grid(row = 6, column = 0, sticky = 'e')
            OptionMenu(self.fr, timeHourThree, *timelistHour).grid(row = 6, column = 1, sticky = 'w')
            Label(self.fr, text = "Minute :").grid(row = 6, column = 1, sticky = 'e')
            OptionMenu(self.fr, timeMinThree, *timelistMinute).grid(row = 6, column = 2, sticky = 'w')
            Label(self.fr, text = "Hour :").grid(row = 7, column = 0, sticky = 'e')
            OptionMenu(self.fr, timeHourThree, *timelistHour).grid(row = 7, column = 1, sticky = 'w')
            Label(self.fr, text = "Minute :").grid(row = 7, column = 1, sticky = 'e')
            OptionMenu(self.fr, timeMinThree, *timelistMinute).grid (row = 7, column = 2, sticky = 'w')
            Label(self.fr, text = "Hour :").grid(row = 8, column = 0, sticky = 'e')
            OptionMenu(self.fr, timeHourThree, *timelistHour).grid(row = 8, column = 1, sticky = 'w')
            Label(self.fr, text = "Minute :").grid(row = 8, column = 1, sticky = 'e')
            OptionMenu(self.fr, timeMinThree, *timelistMinute).grid(row = 8, column = 2, sticky = 'w')
        elif currentValue == 4:
            timeHourFour = StringVar()
            timeHourFour.set(timelistHour[0])
            timeMinFour = StringVar()
            timeMinFour.set(timelistMinute[0])
            Label(self.fr, text = "Hour :").grid(row = 6, column = 0, sticky = 'e')
            OptionMenu(self.fr, timeHourFour, *timelistHour).grid(row = 6, column = 1, sticky = 'w')
            Label(self.fr, text = "Minute :").grid(row = 6, column = 1, sticky = 'e')
            OptionMenu(self.fr, timeMinFour, *timelistMinute).grid(row = 6, column = 2, sticky = 'w')
            Label(self.fr, text = "Hour :").grid(row = 7, column = 0, sticky = 'e')
            OptionMenu(self.fr, timeHourFour, *timelistHour).grid(row = 7, column = 1, sticky = 'w')
            Label(self.fr, text = "Minute :").grid(row = 7, column = 1, sticky = 'e')
            OptionMenu(self.fr, timeMinFour, *timelistMinute).grid(row = 7, column = 2, sticky = 'w')
            Label(self.fr, text = "Hour :").grid(row = 8, column = 0, sticky = 'e')
            OptionMenu(self.fr, timeHourFour, *timelistHour).grid(row = 8, column = 1, sticky = 'w')
            Label(self.fr, text = "Minute :").grid(row = 8, column = 1, sticky = 'e')
            OptionMenu(self.fr, timeMinFour, *timelistMinute).grid(row = 8, column = 2, sticky = 'w')
            Label(self.fr, text = "Hour :").grid(row = 9, column = 0, sticky = 'e')
            OptionMenu(self.fr, timeHourFour, *timelistHour).grid(row = 9, column = 1, sticky = 'w')
            Label(self.fr, text = "Minute :").grid(row = 9, column = 1, sticky = 'e')
            OptionMenu(self.fr, timeMinFour, *timelistMinute).grid(row = 9, column = 2, sticky = 'w')
```

As you can see I have written an if statement for this (with 9 elif statements - in the code above I only posted up until the fourth value but it repeats that until 10). I realised that I could shorten my code by writing a for loop 'on-click' (of the RadioButton). However, I am stuck as to how I should go about writing this loop.

If anyone coould give me any pointers that would be amazing! Tia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a little exemple of what you could possibly do, inside your `timings` function :

```
timeHourTwo = StringVar()
timeHourTwo.set(timelistHour[0])
timeMinTwo = StringVar()
timeMinTwo.set(timelistMinute[0])
def recursion(n):
    Label(self.fr, text = "Hour :").grid(row = (5+n), column = 0, sticky = 'e')
    OptionMenu(self.fr, timeHourTwo, *timelistHour).grid(row = (5+n), column = 1, sticky = 'w')
    Label(self.fr, text = "Minute :").grid(row = (5+n), column = 1, sticky = 'e')
    OptionMenu(self.fr, timeMinTwo, *timelistMinute).grid(row = (5+n), column = 2, sticky = 'w') 
    if n > 1:
        recursion(n-1)
```

It's not perfect as I couldn't test it and as **Labels** won't be sorted as yours (from the biggest to the lowest) but maybe it can inspire you. Hope it helps !

It's based on this :

```
def recursion(n):
    print(5+n)
    if n > 1:
        recursion(n-1)

recursion(4)  #Output : 9 8 7 6
```

Comment: Thanks!!! This has defiantly helped point me in the right direction. Upvoted but wont appear as not got enough rep :)

Comment: No worries. You can put it as the "right answer" if it solved your problem

Comment: Ok. Also how would I grab the currentValue. Before I was using self.y.get. Noticed that you left that out

Comment: You would do it same as before and pass it to n. So if current = self.y.get(), you would pass recursion(current)

Comment: You're right Steven I forgot this point. If you put the recursion inside timings(), maybe you can proceed as @Superspork suggested

Comment: Thanks! Got it working and this has helped a lot. On another note would either of you know how I could restart the function each time it clicked something different. For example, when I click "Once" one line appears then if I click "Twice" two lines appear however, if I go back to "Once" the second line still stays. Think I need a while loop right?

Comment: It's not really clear for me, maybe you should post a new question or edit this one